# Crash when loading UICollectionView in, why?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionreusableview

There is no error log just this what I see.

I have a dynamic prototype UICollectionViewCell, and loading in here:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UICollectionViewCell! {

    var cell: LeftMenuCollectionViewCell

cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("xxx", forIndexPath: indexPath) as LeftMenuCollectionViewCell // <- at this line something goes wrong

    return cell
}
```

I am registering class before:

```
self.collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "xxx")
```

Using iOS 8 beta 5 now

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with the two solution below, I registered cell incorrectly, but afterward I found an other issue, [cell's outlets become nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165195/why-is-uicollectionviewcells-outlet-nil). And the solution for that was to **remove  whole registration**, if UICollectionViewController was created via Interface Builder.

Answer (score 2):

You have registered `UICollectionViewCell` instead of your own cell class `LeftMenuCollectionViewCell`. So that the casting of

```
UICollectionviewCell as LeftMenuCollectionViewCell
```

is breaking and causing the crash. To fix this register the proper class

```
self.collectionView.registerClass(LeftMenuCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "xxx")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have registered the cell incorrectly.  Try this:

```
self.collectionView.registerClass(LeftMenuCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "xxx")
```